# "Did you just...." present or past tense?

Tags: tenses, past-tense

Consider the following two statements, and the tenses.

> - Did you win?
> - You just won.

But what about *Did you just *_*_ a camera*? Would it be followed by *win* or *won*?

Comment: What makes you think the word ‘just’ makes any difference? In “did you win”, _win_ is not a present form; it’s an infinitive. You cannot have two finite forms in the same verbal unit. Also, _e.g._ means ‘for example’ (Latin _exemplī grātiā_ ‘for the sake of an example’), so _for e.g._ means ‘for for example’ and does not make sense.

Comment: I wasn't sure, that's why I'm posting a question.. and wow... this community is pretty harsh in the way downvotes are given

Comment: When questions show no sign of any research or effort on the part of the asker to find an answer to the question before asking here, then yes.

Comment: What research do you suggest I should've done?

Comment: Some people are probably reacting negatively to the assertion that “Did you win?” is in the present tense, because *did* is the simple past form of *to do.*

Comment: I believe a mod edited my question.

Comment: I bet you anything that some native speakers (in their dialect) do say: Did you just won a camera? Did you just went/gone outside? Did you just seen that movie? etc. Instead of using the auxiliary, **have**. Say it quickly, and the phrases roll off the tip of your tongue. They're ungrammatical but *some* native speakers will make these errors. I can't prove it because this deals with speech, a different beast to English when it is written.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Did you win?* is asking about the past. It is the past tense of *do*. Rearranging the words yields *you did win*, which is, essentially, *you won*. There is no need for a *double of the past tense* (you did won).

*You just won* is the same as the above, with the simple addition of a slight modifier, *just*.

***Did you just win a camera?***  Rearranging the words: You did just win a camera = (remember, there is no need for a *double past tense*) you just won a camera.

**Did** you just **won** is two simple past tenses. There is no construction with *did* such as this in English. The correct construction is in the bold above.

Comment: @the8thbit - happy to help. :)

Comment: Alternatively you could say: *Have you just won a camera?*